# Missing required prop: "value" on model/value binding for custom input component in Vue

Tags: vue.js, data-binding, custom-controls, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I followed [this guide](https://learnvue.co/2021/01/everything-you-need-to-know-about-vue-v-model/) while trying to make a custom form component in Vue 3 (composition api, `script setup` mode).

When I load the page containing my component, I get a console warning like this one:

> [Vue warn]: Missing required prop: "value"
> at <SwitchControl key=0 name="question-8" model=undefined  ... >

My component (CSS omitted):

```html
<template>
  <input ref="switchElement"
         v-bind="$attrs"
         class="gui-switch"
         @input="value = !value; emit('update:modelValue', value)"
         type="checkbox"
         role="switch"
         :value="value" />
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { defineEmit, defineProps, onMounted, ref } from "vue"


const props = defineProps<{
  value: boolean | undefined,
}>()

const emit = defineEmit<{
  (e: "update:modelValue", value: boolean | undefined): void,
}>()

const switchElement = ref<HTMLInputElement>()

onMounted(() => switchElement.value!.indeterminate = true)
</script>
```

The page that contains it uses it like so:

```html
<!-- v-for question in questions -->
<switch-control :name="`question-${question.id}`"
             :model="feedbackData[`question-${question.id}`]"
             :id="`question-${question.id}`" />
```

I've tried various things such as changing the name of the emitted event to `input` or using `v-model` instead of `:model` but I haven't managed to fix this yet and I don't know what else to try.

**EDIT:**
Editing the component to use `modelValue` thusly:

```html
<template>
  <input ref="switchElement"
         v-bind="$attrs"
         class="gui-switch"
         @input="modelValue = !modelValue; emit('update:modelValue', modelValue)"
         type="checkbox"
         role="switch"
         :value="modelValue" />
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { defineEmit, defineProps, onMounted, ref } from "vue"


const props = defineProps<{
  modelValue: boolean | undefined,
}>()

const emit = defineEmit<{
  (e: "update:modelValue", value: boolean | undefined): void,
}>()

const switchElement = ref<HTMLInputElement>()

onMounted(() => switchElement.value!.indeterminate = true)
</script>
```

Parent:

```html
<!-- v-for question in questions -->
<switch-control :name="`question-${question.id}`"
             v-model="feedbackData[`question-${question.id}`]"
             :id="`question-${question.id}`" />
```

Leads to an outright error:

```
[Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of scheduler flush. This is likely a Vue internals bug. Please open an issue at https://new-issue.vuejs.org/?repo=vuejs/vue-next
at <SwitchControl key=0 name="question-8" modelValue=undefined  ... > 

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: invalid 'instanceof' operand type
    assertType runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:1877
    validateProp runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:1841
    validateProps runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:1817
    initProps runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:1548
    setupComponent runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:6500
    mountComponent runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4206
    processComponent runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4182
    patch runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:3791
    mountChildren runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:3975
```

**EDIT2:**
I managed to zoom in on whereabouts the problem is, but I still can't quite figure out what's happening.

I changed the component so that `@input` is now `@input="emit('update:modelValue', !modelValue)"`. I'll include the relevant parts of the `<script>` of the page that includes it:

```js
import SwitchControl from "@/components/SwitchControl.vue"
import type { FeedbackQuestion } from "@/utils/api/story"
import { defineProps, ref } from "vue"


const props = defineProps<{
  questions: {id: number}[],
}>()

const defaultModelValues = {
  // These are hard-coded for debugging, ideally I'd want it to work with an empty initial object
  "question-8": null,
  "question-11": null,
}
const feedbackData = ref<Record<string, any>>(defaultModelValues)
```

Now the symptoms:

- When the code looks like the above, with the prop and emit defined as `boolean | undefined`, I get the following error and the whole for loop is not rendered:

```
[Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of scheduler flush. This is likely a Vue internals bug. Please open an issue at https://new-issue.vuejs.org/?repo=vuejs/vue-next 
  at <SwitchControl modelValue=null onUpdate:modelValue=fn<onUpdateModelValue> name="question-8"  ... >

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: invalid 'instanceof' operand type
```

- If instead I annotate the prop and emit as just `boolean`, the elements load, and I only get a warning (see below). If I then try to change the value by clicking on the element, I keep getting the same warning and the value doesn't change at all, instead of alternating true and false as would be expected. The `value` attribute in the HTML if I inspect it, does behave correctly (is "" initially, then alternates between "true" and "false").

```
[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "modelValue". Expected Boolean, got Null  
  at <SwitchControl modelValue=null onUpdate:modelValue=fn<onUpdateModelValue> name="question-8"  ... >
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem in this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-using-vmodel?file=src/App.vue). Also note that props are readonly, so your `@input` handler should not try to toggle `modelValue`.

Comment: @tony19 Please see the EDIT2 to the question, maybe it will hint at something I'm not considering. Thanks for taking the time so far.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the EDIT2 problem in this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-using-vmodel-lw7vpp?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMyForm.vue). Can you share a link to a reproduction?

Comment: I created this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-using-vmodel-utxscj?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/App.vue) copying the structure of my actual app as closely as possible, but it still doesn't error out even though my app does. Do you have any suggestions on things that might be causing the issue? I'm running out of things to try. The constant is the error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: invalid 'instanceof' operand type` but I'm not calling any promise and the stack trace doesn't point to anywhere in my own code, only the esm-bundler.

Comment: The error only goes away if I change the `modelValue` type to remove `undefined`, but then I get a warning because the prop received undefined instead of a boolean. I then have to hardcode the initial modelValues to give, and if I try to derive them dynamically from the props like so: `feedbackData.value = Object.fromEntries(props.questions.map((q) => [`question-${q.id}`, false]))` I get warnings again: the resulting object is logged as being completely empty, as does `props.questions` itself. If I log the object that is passed to `:questions` it does contain the expected array of questions...

Comment: In short, if I log the `questions` variable before it's passed as a prop it's OK, inside the component it's also OK in the template, but anywhere inside the `<script>` it's logged as a proxy with an empty array.

Answer (score 3):

In the child component you should define `value` as `modelValue` :

```
 <input ref="switchElement"
         ...
         :value="modelValue" />
</template>

.....
const props = defineProps<{
  modelValue : boolean | undefined,
}>()
```

and in parent use `v-model` instead of `:model` :

```
  v-model="feedbackData[`question-${question.id}`]"
```

Answer (score 0):

use ref from vue can fix warning message

```
import { defineStore } from "pinia";
import { ref } from "vue";

export const usePosts = defineStore("posts", {
  state: () => {
    return {
      data: [],
      errors: [],
      title: "",
      content: "",
      image: ref(),
    };
  },
});
```

vue file

```
 <q-file color="primary" v-model="postsStore.image" label="Image">
  <template v-slot:prepend>
    <q-icon name="cloud_upload" />
  </template>
 </q-file>
```