# Failed to resolve directive. Unhandled error during execution of scheduler flush

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-directives, vue-script-setup

I'm trying to turn some code into a reusable directive, but I'm getting errors when I load the page that contains it.

This is the file with the directive:

```js
// I also tried "import type"
import { Directive } from "vue"


export const ViewedListener: Directive = {
  mounted(el: HTMLElement, binding) {
    const watcher = document.createElement("span")
    watcher.style.position = "absolute"
    watcher.style.pointerEvents = "none"
    watcher.style.top = (binding.arg || "50") + "%"

    el.style.position = "relative"
    el.parentElement?.insertBefore(watcher, el)

    const hook: IntersectionObserverCallback = (entries, observer) => {
      if (!entries[0].isIntersecting)
        return

      binding.value(entries, observer)
      observer.disconnect()
    }

    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(hook)
    observer.observe(el)
  },
}
```

This is a component where I use it:

```
<template>
  <div v-html="dynamicallyLoadedContent" v-viewed-listener:75="viewHook" />
</template>

<script setup>
import { ViewedListener as vViewedListener } from "@/directives/viewed-listener"

const dynamicallyLoadedContent = "some long html"
</script>
```

When I load the page with the component, I get a bunch of errors:

> [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve directive: viewed-listener

> [Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of scheduler flush. This is likely a Vue internals bug.

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: can't access property "created", binding.dir is undefined

This is an essentially useless error message, it's so vague that it's unusable. I wish they'd improve it and I'd even open an issue about it, but they make it so hard that I lose all motivation to do so as soon as I try to use their playground to make a reproducible example.

Note that the "scheduled flush" error also occurs in another [unsolved problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69588857/missing-required-prop-value-on-model-value-binding-for-custom-input-component) I have. Maybe comparing the two can help find the point of failure.

What am I doing wrong, if anything? I've followed the [short notes on the script setup proposal](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/blob/master/active-rfcs/0040-script-setup.md#using-directives)'s example and I don't think I need to register the directive in main.ts (wouldn't that defeat the purpose of using the composition API?)

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem in this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-troubleshoot-directive?file=src%2FApp.vue).